# CountDownLatch for designing a runway

Tags: java

I am trying to design a solution for problem using countdownlatch. I have only one runway  the flights landing and takeoff should use that runway while one flight is landing or take off the other flight has to wait still the run is free so it tried to implement it through countdownlatch but it is not working can anyone help to find the issue with the below code.

```
public class LandingArrivingFlights {
    private static final int NUM_FLIGHTS = 5;
    private static final int RUNWAY_CAPACITY = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(RUNWAY_CAPACITY);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FLIGHTS; i++) {
            Runway flight = new Runway(i + 1, latch);
            new Thread(flight).start();
        }
    }

    private static class Runway implements Runnable {
        private int flightNum;
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        public Runway(int flightNum, CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.flightNum = flightNum;
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                // Wait for runway availability
                latch.await();

                // Land/take off the flight
                if (flightNum % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Flight " + flightNum + " is taking off.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Flight " + flightNum + " is landing.");
                }

                // Release the runway
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to join() all your threads otherwise the program will exit after the loop.

Comment: and you didnt understand what CDL does...you don't release a CDL, you count down until it reaches 0 and then all threads pass through it. all threads which await() will be blocked, until other threads will reduce the latch to 0. so your program does nothing. all thread are blocked.

Comment: I stared learning CDL and i wanted to understand by implementing this sample can you help me out by changing the code so i can get an idea about the CDL.I could not get your solutions on the comment you gave me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of concurrency structures you need:

- `CountDownLatch` to track completion of all jobs and
- `Semaphore` to control exclusive access to the limited resource

See an example:

```
private static final int NUM_FLIGHTS = 5;
private static final int RUNWAY_CAPACITY = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(RUNWAY_CAPACITY);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(NUM_FLIGHTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FLIGHTS; i++) {
        Runway flight = new Runway(i + 1, semaphore, latch);
        new Thread(flight).start();
    }
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("All flights have been managed.");
}

private static class Runway implements Runnable {
    private final int flightNum;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public Runway(int flightNum, Semaphore semaphore, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.flightNum = flightNum;
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Wait for runway availability
            semaphore.acquire(1);

            // Land/take off the flight
            if (flightNum % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flight " + flightNum + " is taking off [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Flight " + flightNum + " is landing [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Release the runway
            semaphore.release(1);

            // Notify main thread about completion
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```